# Is there any way to hide taskbar labels and not combine taskbar buttons?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

There are three options for customizing taskbar buttons in Windows 7:

1. Always combine, hide labels
2. Combine when taskbar is full
3. Never combine

Is there any way to hide labels and not combine taskbar buttons? Or even better, to exclude only certain applications from combining?

My main problem is that I switch a lot between two instances of a single application, and having to hover over combined icon and then choosing the correct one. Alt-Tabbing is not a good alternative when I'm switching between more than three applications; clicking on taskbar only once is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'd still like to know if there's a way to exclude/include certain applications.

Comment: Another possible solution is to put the taskbar in vertical position on the left or right edge of the screen.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It's something of a hack job, but [this might do the trick](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/21233-taskbar-change-icon-button-width-size.html)! It requires doing a bit of registry editing to shrink the taskbar icons so that the labels auto-hide.

**Set taskbar options**

1. Open Taskbar properties.
2. In the "Taskbar Appearance" group, change the "Taskbar Button" option to "Never combine" if you don't want stacking.

**Adding/editing the registry entry**

1. Press Windows Key + R to open the run command
2. Type int "regedit" (without quotes) and press OK
3. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
4. Find the "MinWidth" entry.
5. If it is not there, right click on an empty space and select New -> String Value. Name this entry "MinWidth" (without quotes)
6. Double click on the MinWidth entry. If you want just the buttons to show, set this to 38 if you're using small buttons, 52 if you're using large buttons (or 54 in Windows 8). Otherwise any value above 38 will work. If you set a value below 38, the buttons will behave oddly. If your main display (on Windows 8.1 or later) has non-standard DPI (e.g. it's Retina or 4k display) you might need to multiply these numbers by the factor of 1.25, 1.5 or 2. Otherwise buttons will shrink / animate incorrectly.
7. Log off and log back in or restart to see the changes.

**Deleting/Uninstalling**

1. Press Windows Key + R to open the run command
2. Type int "regedit" (without quotes) and press OK
3. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
4. Find the "MinWidth" entry and delete it.
5. Log off and log back in or restart to see the changes.

Comment: I can't believe it, this actually does exactly what I wanted! Thanks a bunch, I was afraid that it simply wasn't possible.

Comment: How do you turn on large buttons?

Comment: +1 I started doing this on the Release Candidate and now I do it for all Windows 7 installs I do.

Comment: Reportedly does not work on Windows 8 Release Preview...http://superuser.com/questions/431673/windows-8-never-combine-hide-labels

Comment: [Reportedly](http://superuser.com/questions/553092/windows-8-taskbar-hide-labels-never-combine) works in Windows 8 RTM.

Comment: If you use 52 for large buttons, as per the answer, the taskbar shrinks every time you open a pinned application. 54 seems to be the width of large pinned icons.

Comment: For me it turned out that he value 56 is the optimal one (when using large icons and aero enabled).

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this more than once!  I always come back and refer to this answer for every laptop that I get!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Windows 10 20H1 (May 2020 update) build :(

Answer (score 30):

This is an old question, but the answer of **Kyle B.** didn't work well for me (glitches and flickering), so I'd like to propose an alternative solution.

1. Configure your taskbar for **Always combine, hide labels**.
2. Download [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).
3. Select the **Don't combine grouped buttons** option.

[image: 7+ Taskbar Tweaker]

**The end result:**

[image: don't combine, hide labels]

---

As a bonus, **7+ Taskbar Tweaker** also allows you to configure this option per application:

[image: configuring per application]

Comment: I tried using this with [Bins](http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/) and got some odd behavior. I found that the grouping/combining settings of 7+TT conflict with Bins. By leaving 7+TT's grouping/combining settings as default, using Bins, *and* applying the above registry tweak, I was able to achieve the effect I wanted and still make use of the other tweaks this program has.

Comment: 7+ Taskbar Tweaker works great.  I like the extra options it offers.

Comment: `As a bonus, 7+ Taskbar Tweaker also allows you to configure this option per application:`

Use `Combine` instead of `Group`, when grouping app icons are not dragged all together

Answer (score 1):

***This is an old question**, however as Win 10 is still missing this option, I'm  willing to leave this answer here:*

1. Under taskbar settings, choose "Always, hide labels"
2. Use one of the following options to disable taskbar combining:

**option1: edit the registry**

- Go to the following Registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

- On the right, create a new **32-Bit DWORD** value *NoTaskGrouping*
- Set its value data to 1 in decimals
- Restart Windows 10

**option2: edit group policy editor**

- Launch the Group Policy Editor app (***gpedit.msc***)
- Set the option "*User Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ Start Menu and Taskbar \ Prevent grouping of taskbar items*" to **Enabled**

For more illustrations you could check this link: https://winaero.com/disable-taskbar-button-combining-windows-10/

Regards,

Bishoy

Comment: I just tried the Group Policy option, but it locked in "Never" under the Taskbar settings, so it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Registry key does the same as taskbar settings