# Force Pinned taskbar items to be "icon only" all the time in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

By default (at least in my installation), pinned items on the taskbar will be "icon only" when they have no active windows, but when there are active window, the icon expanded to include text (typically some portion of the title text).

I'm looking for a way to either:

**A (preferred option):**
For any single pinned item, force this pinned item to always display as just the icon even if it has active windows.

OR

**B (acceptable option):**
Force ALL pinned items to always display as icon only in the taskbar

Comment: With regards to setting this sort of option on a finer setting (ie, application by application), you may wish to see http://superuser.com/questions/35304/windows-7-hiding-the-taskbar-label-for-specific-applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution!  This little application allows lables to be hidden per application ID.  I think it is exactly what you and I have been looking for.

http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker

Comment: Open "7+ Taskbar Tweaker", click on "Taskbar Inspector", Make a right click on the parent / grouping entry of the window you want to hide, click on "Show labels: Never".

Answer (score 3):

Right click the taskbar and hit `Properties`. From here, check the `Taskbar` tab and set the **Taskbar Buttons** option.

You want to hide the names of the programs, which Windows refers to as "Hide Labels".
This means using the **Always combine, hide labels** option.

If you want to hide labels *without* enabling combining, check out the SU question [Hide taskbar labels without combining](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/hide-taskbar-labels-without-combining) for some advice in that area.

These will affect *every* taskbar icon.

Comment: Is there any way to affect ONLY pinned items while keeping behavior of regular non-pinned buttons the same (e.g. non-pinned buttons have icon+label while pinned items are icon-only)?

Comment: @Robert Not that I am aware of, and a quick web search (after seeing your comment on Joshua's answer) has yielded no results either I'm afraid.

Comment: This plus your comment above answers my question.  This is a more specific version of the question alluded to in your comment http://superuser.com/questions/35304/windows-7-hiding-the-taskbar-label-for-specific-applications  Someone may want to merge them.

Comment: @Robert, I wouldn't worry about merging. [Some duplication is good](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), and this question is subtly different from the other.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Task Bar and choose Properties. You should see two drop down boxes the second one is "Taskbar Buttons:" change the option here to "Always combine, hide labels".

Comment: This would work if I wanted to hide the labels for ALL taskbar buttons, but I'm looking to hide the labels ONLY for pinned taskbar buttons, but still show the full label for non-pinned buttons.

Answer (score 0):

"Combine if taskbar is full" has that effect. It looks like this:

[image: Taskbar element, unlabeled]

Note how the two pinned apps (XAMPP and Explorer) are only represented as buttons, while the other two apps have labels. If I was to launch one of them, it'd look like this:

[image: Taskbar element labeled]

Is that what you need?

Comment: Afraid not.  The point was to have pinned items stay icon only even when they are launched.  while having all other windows (in my ideal world) not combine and show labels.  Probably I am going to just suck it up and replace the taskbar with a dock such as rocketdock (as I did when I had XP).  I was hoping with the taskbar improvements it could work for me, but I really hate the expanding pinned icon (even though it ought to be just a minor annoyance), and really need to have the labels for less frequently used things.