# Windows 7 Taskbar: Per Program Display Settings?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I am curious if anyone has found a way to set those "Group" and "Display name" setting for the taskbar for individual items? I would love to have some entries as a single icon, no matter how many windows are behind them, and some "ungrouped", so I can quickly access any window.

Comment: Usually such a setting resides in the application's own settings dialog, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but I asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/hide-taskbar-labels-without-combining) a while ago. In this way, everything is an icon and doesn't take much space, and grouped entries are still grouped, although not behind a single icon; but that simply means one click less to get to the grouped entries. Here's an example how active, inactive and grouped icons look:

[image: example of "ungrouped" iconized Win7 taskbar entries]

If that's not good enough for you, check the answer to my question anyway - it'll tell you where taskbar settings are in the registry, maybe you'll find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the Windows orb, select properties>taskbar Tab> Taskbar buttons dropdown, set it to "always combine, hide labels" Hit OK.

[image]

Comment: This setting is a global setting and I think the user wants to set it on a per-application basis. The only settings that are available _out of the box_ are "Always combine, hide labels," "Combine when taskbar is full," and "Never combine." (Sounds like an _opportunity_ for some enterprising software developer.)