# Win 7 task bar buttons - combine or not

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to hide taskbar labels and not combine taskbar buttons?](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons)

Is it possible to force some buttons never combine and others always combine?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest that people have come from my attempts when I used 7 a lot.

> [OP](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons)
>
> It's something of a hack job, but this might do the trick! It requires doing a bit of registry editing to shrink the taskbar icons so that the labels auto-hide.
>
> Set taskbar options
>
> Open Taskbar properties.
>
> In the "Taskbar Appearance" group, change the "Taskbar Button" option to "Never combine" if you don't want stacking.
>
> Adding/editing the registry entry
>
> Press Windows Key + R to open the run command
>
> Type int "regedit" (without quotes) and press OK
>
> Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Control Panel -> Desktop -> WindowMetrics
>
> Find the "MinWidth" entry.
>
> If it is not there, right click on an empty space and select New -> String Value. Name this entry "MinWidth" (without quotes)
>
> Double click on the MinWidth entry. If you want just the buttons to show, set this to 38
>
> if you're using small buttons, 52 if you're using large buttons. Otherwise any value above 38 will work. If you set a value below 38, the buttons will behave oddly.
>
> Log off and log back in or restart to see the changes.
>
> Deleting/Uninstalling
>
> Press Windows Key + R to open the run command
>
> Type int "regedit" (without quotes) and press OK
>
> Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Control Panel -> Desktop -> WindowMetrics
>
> Find the "MinWidth" entry and delete it.
>
> Log off and log back in or restart to see the changes.

Comment: Since you've quoted another SU question, I've flagged this as a duplicate and voted to close.