# How do I run Opera as a different user in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, opera-blink

I'd like to run a second instance of Opera as a different user because I didn't find any other way to have two instances running at the same time.

For this purpose I created a second user for Opera (with admin rights). Then I gave the main user full control over the Opera-User's folder (c:\Users\Opera2). Now the second instance of Opera starts when I run it as a different user but it hangs and nothing works. The window opens but the welcome tab is loading and loading and loading...

I guess my main account still does not have sufficient rights to run the other Opera. Do you know what else I have to set so that it works?

EDIT:

Perhaps I should add that when I login into the Opera2 account Opera works without problems.

Comment: I created the new tag `Opera-Blink`. We should avoid versions so I decided to use `-Blink` as distinction. Maybe `Opera-15+` is also a valid choice, don't know

Comment: I have tried to add exacly those two tags and I think they are both general and specific enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Opera 15+** (Blink engine) you could use a command line switch to specify a different user data directory. This is possible because many switches from Chromium work in Opera 15+ too

```
launcher.exe --user-data-dir="C:\folder\to\second\profile"
```

http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

---

For old **Opera 12** (Presto engine) there is a similar command line switch

```
Opera.exe -PD "C:\folder\to\second\profile"
```

Comment: You are my hero today :) I wonder how did you know this switch but now I googled for it and my approach was wrong because I was looking for Opera switches and not a Chromium ones. It now works even better then having two profiles.

Comment: I was also googling and found Chromium's `--profile-directory `but it doesn't seem to work on Opera 15+

Comment: The next question that I had just after I've created a shortcut for the second Opera was [Is there any way to hide taskbar labels and not combine taskbar buttons?](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons) but fortunately this already had an answer. Just as a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new tab, then drag the tab out of the window to create a second instance of Opera.

Comment: Sure, I know it's possible to have two windows like this but what I'd like to have is two profiles to be able to save different tabs for different instances. Dev and wok stuff in one instance and private stuff in the other instance... and it wasn't me who voted you down :]

Comment: Ah okay. I misunderstood your question. Given that the answer already has been given, I won't edit mine. Although a second idea would be using a portable version of Opera. Given that it doesn't need an installation it would always work.

Comment: Or use [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?DownloadSandboxie)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [portable version of Opera](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/opera_portable) to get your second instance.

Comment: This is the old Opera 12. There is no need to use this PortableApps version since Opera 12 has a portable mode by design inbuild. just select portable mode in the normal installer. Of course there is a portable mode in the Opera 26 installer too