# Windows 10 Taskbar: Never combine, always hide labels

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar

**Is there a way to never combine task bar icons, but still not display their labels?**

This worked on Windows 7 with a registry hack found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons), but it doesn't work as expected on Windows 10. It is especially useful if you have multiple instances open, you know their order and you want to save this one click you always have to make when they're combined.

**Not an option here**

[image: menu]

**Example of what I'd like:**

[image: example]

Is this possible without *3rd party applications*? Preferably using a registry hack.

**Note:** It is possible using a simple Registry hack in Windows 7, however, it's a completely different story for Windows 10.

Comment: Did you mean Preferably?

Comment: How did you get the white text? I know a little hack but it only gives black text.

Comment: What white text? You mean of the windows title bar? That's Windows 10 Threshold 2. And the second picture is photoshopped.

Comment: The white text on top of the titlebar. `Taskbar and Start Menu Properties`

Comment: That's the current version of Windows 10 you can get through updates by now. It has been this way in the preview for months, though.

Comment: Related: [This older post](http://superuser.com/q/30007/109256) asked exactly this question, except for Windows 7. The answers mentioned registry hack and third-party tool. Not sure if still applicable for Windows 10.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but it only works on Windows 7 through 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to hide taskbar labels and not combine taskbar buttons?](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons)

Comment: Not a duplicate! This is an easy registry hack for Windows 7. However, for Windows 10 this is **completely** different.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Though this doesn't completely answer your question,

This was possible till Windows 8.1 using the minWidth registry hack found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons).

In Windows 10, it is possible if you move your taskbar to a side...

[image: Placing the taskbar to one side.]

[image: Taskbar Properties.]

Or, You could use a 3rd party program called 7+ Taskbar Tweaker...(It was recently updated to work with Win 10.)

[image]

Result...[image]

Comment: In the end, I installed 7 Tweaker. I didn't want to, because it was just this minor feature that I needed, but I had to, since there is no alternative.

Comment: @bytecode77 Or you could have just adapted with the taskbar to the side...just joking...Taskbar tweaker has other features too, which you can try out...

Comment: good you added "Just joking" :D Yeah, I really don't need any of this, I tried the features. I really like Windows with as little modification as possible. But this is something I need. I'm giving you +1, but I won't accept the answer and see if someone comes along with a registry solution.

Comment: I already have the taskbar on the left, but there's still a tiny bit of text poking out, see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSgIF.png). Do you know how to get rid of it?