# How to display same windows side by side on taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can windows be displayed side by side instead of overlapping on taskbar :

[image]

Right clicking &including holding shift key) on taskbar dows not appear to contain this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-how-buttons-appear-on-the-taskbar

**To change how programs and buttons appear on the taskbar**

1. Open Taskbar and Start Menu Properties by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel**, clicking **Appearance and Personalization**, and then clicking **Taskbar and Start Menu.**
2. Under **Taskbar appearance,** select one of the options from the **Taskbar buttons** list:

   - Always combine, hide labels
   - Combine when taskbar is full
   - Never combine
3. To use small icons, select the **Use small icons** check box. To use large icons, clear the check box.
4. Click **OK**.

But you cannot for example hide labels + never combine without getting your hands dirty; relevant superuser:
[Is there any way to hide taskbar labels and not combine taskbar buttons?](https://superuser.com/questions/30007/is-there-any-way-to-hide-taskbar-labels-and-not-combine-taskbar-buttons)

EDIT: Oh, @gronostay mentioned the link already; just leaving for sake of completeness.